# How can I compute the differential of this map $(t,x)\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} e^t &xe^t \\ 0 & e^{-t} \end{pmatrix}$ going into a submanifold?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, manifolds, differential

> Let me define $G:=\left\{a(t)= \begin{pmatrix}
> a &b \\
> 0 & a^{-1}
> \end{pmatrix}, a>0, b\in\Bbb{R}\right\}$ and view it as a submanifold of $M_2(\Bbb{R})$. Then define the map
> $\phi:\Bbb{R}\times \Bbb{R}\rightarrow G, (t,x)\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
> e^t &xe^t \\
> 0 & e^{-t}
> \end{pmatrix}$. I would like to compute $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}(\phi(t,x))$

I know that by definition $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}(\phi(t,x)):=D(\phi)_{\phi^{-1}(\phi(t,x))}(e_1)=D(\phi)_{(t,x)}(e_1)$ which is a map from $\Bbb{R}^2\rightarrow T_{(t,x)}G$. Now my problem is that I don't know how to compute $D(\phi)_{(t,x)}(e_1)$, since I cannot compute the Jacobian matrix and multiply by $e_1$.
Can maybe somone help me to understand how one can compute this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $G$ is the tangent space at the identity of $G$ which consists of matrices of the form

$$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
0 & -a
\end{pmatrix}
$$

This space has a basis

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

To find the tangent space at $\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
0 & a^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}$ you can just translate this basis, so a basis at $\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
0 & a^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}$ is

$$\begin{pmatrix}
a & -b\\
0 & -a^{-1}
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

In your case the corresponding basis at $\phi(t,x)$ is $\begin{pmatrix}
e^t & -xe^t\\
0 & -e^{-t}
\end{pmatrix}$,$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & e^t\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

The $t$ and $x$ partial derivatives of your map are given by

$$\begin{pmatrix}
e^t & xe^t\\
0 & -e^{-t}
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
0 & e^t\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$.

The coordinates of these partial derivatives in the above basis are $(1,1+x)$ and $(0,1)$

Putting this together gives that with respect to these bases the Jacobian at $(t,x)$ is

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
1+x & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Could you explain what you meant by translate the basis?

Comment: I just mean to multiply the basis elements on the left by the matrix corresponding to the point you want to translate to. This works because left multiplication is a diffeomorphism of $G$ whose pushforward is given by left multiplication.

Comment: Ah okey I see. and how do you get the partial derivatives of my map?

Comment: they are just the entrywise derivatives with respect to both $t$ and $x$

Comment: So the first matrix is w.r.t t and the second w.r.t x?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149249/discussion-between-sam-ballas-and-user1294729).

Comment: But wouldn't I then have $-xe^t$ instead of $xe^t$?

Comment: No, we are taking $t$ and $x$ derivatives of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}e^t & xe^t\\ 0 & e^{-t}\end{pmatrix}$, so the $t$ derivative of the (1,2) entry is $xe^t$

Comment: and what about the second basis matrix?

Comment: The two matrices that make up the basis correspond to translating the basis at the origin. We never take derivatives of these matrices. What we are taking partial derivatives of is the map $\phi$ that you want to compute the Jacobian of

Comment: Can I explain you in the chat what I have understood so that you see where I'm stuck?